# How to create date picker without using any type of dialog or model in android

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter

I want to create this type of image without using any model or an alert dialog box. This is a simple layout
so how to achieve this spinner date picker without any popup/dialog/modal in a simple screen with some other Views

[image]

Comment: You can try this library: [link](https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker)

Comment: It's Cupertino styled Date picker. Flutter has a baked-in widget for it, or there are libs out there on pub.

Comment: @TirthPatel sir I want this in native android

Comment: Then why did you tag "flutter". I came because of that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DatePicker` with mode set as `spinner` in android.

```
<DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner" />
```

It will give you following result -

[image]

Happy Coding !!